# xgboost Installation error

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, xgboost

After installing xgboost successfully when I imported xgboost in anaconda I got this error

```
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:49:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xgboost
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost-0.4-py3.5.egg\xgboost\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .core import DMatrix, Booster
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost-0.4-py3.5.egg\xgboost\core.py", line 112, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xgboost-0.4-py3.5.egg\xgboost\core.py", line 106, in _load_lib
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 425, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 1114] A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're still having environment issues I would suggest using this [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/datmo/xgboost/~/dockerfile/). This allows us to work independently of local python, which I have found very helpful to replicate the environment on any other system. You might also find Datmo conversion useful to facilitate this.

DISCLAIMER: I work at this company called [Datmo](https://datmo.com/), which is building a community of developers by simplifying the machine learning workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Anaconda, re-installed it and followed the XGBoost installation steps available on the web to fix the issue.